# Yum fails with - There are no enabled repos.

Tags: linux, installation, yum

I'm trying to install "libstdc++.i686" with

```
yum install libstdc++.i686
```

but it failes beacuse of this error:

> qa@qa-teamcity01:/usr/local/nsis/nsis-2.46-src$ sudo yum install
>   libstdc++.i686
>
> [sudo] password for qa:
>
> **There are no enabled repos.  **Run "yum repolist all" to see the repos
>   you have.**
>
> **You can enable repos with yum-config-manager --enable**

---

I've looked at my repos.d directory (/etc/yum/repos.d) and its empty,
and opend yum.conf file and didn't see any repositories.

How do i get the repositery that i need?

Comment: Check the answers to http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6827/how-to-add-a-repository-on-fedora

Comment: its only for fedora OS, I'm using ubunto

Comment: The usual way to install packages on the command line in Ubuntu is with apt-get.  Try _sudo apt-get install libstdc++.i686_  (and if you are running a 32bit version of Ubuntu you can drop the .i686 part)

Comment: yum is not configured, or starts with absolutely no config files. provided you install it with `sudo apt install yum`. I would also like some help with this issue... There are no repos to enable, just none period. yum is not configured to look anywhere for packages. I guess i need to spin up a fedora vm and check what the configs are supposed to be. In your case, just use apt, as you are running ubuntu instead of fedora. (sorry for bugging you, this is to try to get help for my use case, which is i want fedora packages on ubuntu, it could be a duplicate of any new question i make(same error))

Answer (score 30, accepted):

ok,
so my problem was that I tried to install the package with **yum** which is the primary tool for getting, installing, deleting, querying, and managing Red Hat Enterprise Linux RPM software packages from official Red Hat software repositories, as well as other third-party repositories.

But I'm using ubuntu and The usual way to install packages on the command line in Ubuntu is with apt-get. so the right command was:

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++.i686
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me, sudo apt-get install libstdc++.i686
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libstdc++.i686
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libstdc++.i686'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libstdc++.i686'

Comment: This isn't really an answer to yum issue that has been presented. It shouldn't be an accepted answer